# aplicacion modo release se bloquea

Tags: android, android-studio

hola realize una mini app para vender ciertos productos personales
cuando la compilo y las pruebo en diferentes celulares y en el emulador, la app trabaja muy bien
cuando genero el App Bundle o el APk e instalo con bundletools la aplicacion se detiene.
e realizado varias prebas y parece ser que el problema radica cuando consulto el cloud firestore

```
    mStoragrDB.collection(groupoid +"Destacados")
            .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (!task.getResult().isEmpty()) {
                temp.clear();
                lista.clear();
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot docuemnt : task.getResult()) {
                    if (docuemnt.exists()) {
                        String descripcion = docuemnt.get("cantidad").toString();
                        if (descripcion.equals("Destacado"))
                        {
                            temp.add(medidaclass);
                            destacado.add(docuemnt.get("codigo").toString(););
                        } else lista.add(docuemnt.get("codigo").toString(););

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

este es un listado que me define ciertos productos en la pantalla principal.
ahora todo este codigo en modo debug trabaja bien
modo Release
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Modo debug[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo unico que puedo aclarar que parece ser el FirebaseFirestore
ya que cuando elimino la busqueda y compilo no genera error, logicamente no busca ningun dato pero si

ahora no se a que se deba y no encuentro por ningun lado cual podria ser el error

si alguien tiene alguna idea o consego por favor lo agradeceria:

Me gustaria aclarar que ando compilando con la misma firma lo unico que cambia es cuando compilo a modo release y no debug
si compilo en modo debug generando el apk, este funciona bien
si compilo en modo release generando el apk este genera error cuando consulta firestore
este problema pasa tanto en Apk Bundle como APK
e buscado alguna referencia y no encuentro ninguna documentacion
anexo gradable

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.gowaoo.gowaoobay"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.4"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        signingConfigs {
            release {
                keyAlias 'key0'
                keyPassword 'clavepass'
                storeFile file('C:\\xxyyzz\\nombrekey.jks')
                storePassword 'clavepass'
            }
            debug {
                keyAlias 'key0'
                keyPassword 'clavepass'
                storeFile file('C:\\xxyyzz\\nombrekey.jks')
                storePassword 'clavepass'
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false                        
            minifyEnabled true                     
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}


    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta8'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.1.9'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:dc-volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Decir "se bloquea" se debe a infinidad de razones, revisa en Analytics en la consola de Google Play, puedes revisar el LogCat?.

Answer (score 0):

hola despues de tanto buscar comparto con ustedes la solucion
1er cuando publicas una app no puedes colcar log por medidas de seguridad esto me llevo a identificar donde estaba la falla y era en el cloud firebase
ahora porque en el cloud firebase?
estaba obteniendo la informacion de firebase por medio de clases las cuales usas setter estas a su vez cuando compilas en modo release el proguard-rules elimina el codigo que no se usa, entonces proguard eliminaba los setter y no podia obtener los datos del firestore
generando un error nullexception
por lo tanto me vi obligado a forzar el proguard para que no eliminara ese codigo no usable y compilarlo
esto el problema

hay que aclarar que firebase si recuperaba la informacion de la tabla mas no la asignaba a la clase porque proguard eliminaba ese codigo o inutilizable

espero y le sirva a alguien mas

Decir "se bloquea" se debe a infinidad de razones, revisa en Analytics en la consola de Google Play, puedes revisar el LogCat?
estoy de acuardo, por eso me toco analizar codigo a ver donde y la razon que se bloqueaba